# package doesnt up openxml .net core

Tags: c#, openxml

i have used this link to create an openxml package https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/how-to-create-a-package of word document but am getting below error while opening the word document.

"This file was created in pre release version of 2007 and cannot be opening in this version". i have 2016 installed.

when i have used the below approach it creates the document and i can open it with out any issue.

```
using (var document = WordprocessingDocument.Create(
            @"test.docx", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                document.AddMainDocumentPart();
                document.MainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(
                            new Body(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("some text")))));
            }
```

Wanted to know what is the issue with the first option as i have to create document using xml only.

Comment: Microsoft enhanced Office between release 2003 and 2007,  So there is a hidden version number on each object in Office.  The extension of the files are also different like 2003 is doc and 2007 is docx.  A word document is divided into sections so you can have a 2003 section in a 2007 document (not the opposite).  So the error message indicates the entire file (is doc) and the SDK (your link) does not support a doc (2003).  If you open the file in a version of 2007 Office (or other tool) and SaveAs a 2007 (or later) with extension docs it should work.  Sometime just rename file to docx works.

Comment: Thank you for your response @jdweng. i have created a word document supported by the open xml sdk(extension docx) but couldnt open the document. any help to the link to create dcox using openxml from xml format

Comment: You may need a different version of the SDK.

Comment: the issue is resolved changed the xmlns from https to http in the provided link code. thank you jdweng

Comment: That is not a namespace. You are changing the IP Application Mode.  https is secure mode and http is non secure mode.  HTTP is an application layer.